# How can I write code that optionally uses a module if it exists?

Tags: perl, module, require

If I want to write code that optionally uses a module how can I do it? For example, if I want to write code that `warn`s Dumping an object if `Data::Dumper` is available or otherwise just `warn`s, how can I do that?

Comment: This question should not have been closed as a duplicate because there are two parts to the question.  1. How to optionally load a module and 2. How to optionally use a subroutine.

Comment: The answer to #2 is this. `use constant haveDumper => defined &Dumper; sub warning { haveDumper ? warn(Dumper @_) : warn(@_); }`  The general way to check for a subroutine being available is `defined &NAME`.  This matters because subroutines could be supplied by various modules.  If you need to check for a subroutine that is autoloaded, use `exists &NAME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an effective idiom for loading an optional module,

```
use constant has_Module => defined eval { require Module };
```

This will require the module if available, and store the status in a constant.

You can use this like,

```
use constant has_DataDumper => defined eval { require Data::Dumper };

warn "got object";
if ( has_DataDumper ) {
  warn Data::Dumper::Dumper( $obj );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```perl
BEGIN {
   if (eval { require Data::Dumper }) {
      *dumper = sub { warn(Data::Dumper::Dumper(@_)) };
   } else {
      *dumper = sub { };
   }
}

dumper(...);
```

---

The downside of the above is that expensive expressions passed as arguments still need to be calculated if Data::Dumper isn't available.

```perl
use constant has_dumper => eval { require Data::Dumper };

BEGIN {
   if (has_dump) {
      *dumper = sub { warn(Data::Dumper::Dumper(@_)) };
   } else {
      *dumper = sub { };
   }
}

dumper(...);                # Ok
dumper(...) if has_dumper;  # Statement completely optimized away if DD missing.
```