# How can I write a SIG{__DIE__} handler that does not trigger in eval blocks?

Tags: perl, signals, eval, die, carp

According to the [`perldoc -f die`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die), which documents `$SIG{__DIE__}`

> Although this feature was to be run only right before your program was to exit, this is not currently so: the `$SIG{__DIE__}` hook is currently called even inside evaled blocks/strings! If one wants the hook to do nothing in such situations, put `die @_ if $^S;` as the first line of the handler (see `$^S` in perlvar). Because this promotes strange action at a distance, this counterintuitive behavior may be fixed in a future release.

So let's take a basic signal handler which will trigger with `eval { die 42 }`,

```
package Stupid::Insanity {
  BEGIN { $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { print STDERR "ERROR"; exit; }; }
}
```

We make this safe with

```
package Stupid::Insanity {
  BEGIN { $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { return if $^S; print STDERR "ERROR"; exit; }; }
}
```

Now this will **NOT** trigger with `eval { die 42 }`, but it will trigger when that same code is in a `BEGIN {}` block like

```
BEGIN { eval { die 42 } }
```

This may seem obscure but it's rather real-world as you can see it being [used in this method here (where the `require` fails and it's caught by an `eval`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64918979/124486), or in my case specifically here [`Net::DNS::Parameters`](https://metacpan.org/source/NLNETLABS/Net-DNS-1.29/lib%2FNet%2FDNS%2FParameters.pm#L377). You may think you can catch the compiler phase too, like this,

```
BEGIN {
  $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    return if ${^GLOBAL_PHASE} eq 'START' || $^S;
    print STDERR "ERROR";
    exit;
  };
}
```

Which will work for the above case, but alas it will **NOT** work for a require of a document which has a BEGIN statement in it,

```
eval "BEGIN { eval { die 42 } }";
```

Is there anyway to solve this problem and write a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler that doesn't interfere with `eval`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Check `caller(1)`

Just a bit further down the rabbit hole with `[caller(1)]->[3] eq '(eval)'`

```
return if [caller(1)]->[3] eq '(eval)' || ${^GLOBAL_PHASE} eq 'START' || $^S;
```

### Crawl entire call stack

You can crawl the entire stack and be sure you're **NOT** deeply in an eval with,

```
for ( my $i = 0; my @frame = caller($i); $i++ ) {
  return if $frame[3] eq '(eval)'
}
```

---

Yes, this is total insanity. Thanks to mst on `irc.freenode.net/#perl` for the pointer.

Comment: You asked and got an answer. Why is that insanity? This is Holy Grail of other languages: introspection. :-).

Comment: Now, what would be insane would be to use that without a BIG comment explaining it. Remember: Always have pity on the poor slob that has to look at your code six months from now. Especially since it might be *you*.

:-)

Comment: @mpersico my comment links to this question. ;)

Comment: There's module Eval::Util on CPAN, which has functions for telling you if you're inside an eval.